# How to change a letter in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

How can i change a letter in my textbox?

For example when a user types "L" there will be typed"N". as i work with axshockwavflash and need to work connection between flash and c# there are many words undefiend for other languages in flash and i have to put a replace for it.i worked with text.replace() function but it didnt work for my case. i used it like below:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text.Replace("ی","ي");
}
```

Comment: please confirm it, a word or a letter?

Comment: that was my mistake "letter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning:

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("ی","ي");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember, a String is immutable. This means that when you do a .Replace on it, the original string is not changed. A copy is made. Therefore, it will only work if you set the text to this new value. Like I do below

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("ی","ي");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a dictionary to hold all the necessary entries of your mapping and handle the `KeyPress` event like this:

```
Dictionary<char,char> dict = new Dictionary<char,char>();
//Initialize your dict, this should be done somewhere in your form constructor
dict['L'] = 'N';
dict['A'] = 'B';
//....
//KeyPress event handler for your textBox1
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){
   char c;
   if(dict.TryGetValue(e.KeyChar, out c)) e.KeyChar = c;
}
```

**NOTE**: In case to prevent user from pasting some unwanted text, you can try catching the message `WM_PASTE`, get the text from clipboard and set the corrected text back to clipboard like this:

```
public class NativeTextBox : NativeWindow {
    public Dictionary<char, char> CharMappings;
    public NativeTextBox(Dictionary<char,char> charMappings){
      CharMappings = charMappings;
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == 0x302){ //WM_PASTE
            string s = Clipboard.GetText();
            foreach (var e in CharMappings){
              s = s.Replace(e.Key, e.Value);
            }                
            Clipboard.SetText(s);
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
//Then hook it up like this (place in your form constructor)
new NativeTextBox(dict).AssignHandle(textBox1.Handle);
```